# Sistema Multi-tenant com possibilidade de "personalização"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, saas

Estou levantando conhecimentos para a criação de um sistema multi-tenant. Já andei dando uma olhada em algumas referências do MSDN, do SOEN e do SOPT, assim como de alguns sites diversos.

Apesar de ler as referências, mesmo esclarecendo muitas dúvidas, ainda restam algumas questões que ainda não são totalmente claras para mim. Por isso decidi vir aqui para ver se conseguiria elucidá-las.

Nas referências que eu li, os dois modelos para trabalhar com *multi-tenant* que mais me chamaram atenção foram:

**Sistemas isolados**

Esta abordagem tem algumas vantagens, como a facilidade de criar o código e não se preocupar tanto com questões relacionadas à segurança. Porém, acredito que seja uma facilidade ilusória, e, como dito, somente para o desenvolvimento da aplicação, pois a manutenção do sistema tornaria-se onerosa a medida que o número de clientes aumentasse.

Utilizando esta abordagem também permitiria a possibilidade da customização ou personalização do sistema para as necessidades específicas do cliente. E esta possibilidade é importante para este sistema.

**Sistema compartilhado**

Esta abordagem dificulta o desenvolvimento da aplicação tendo em vista que a segurança deve ser mais bem elaborada para evitar acesso não autorizado à dados que não pertencem ao *tenant*. Porém a manutenção do sistema seria refletida para todos os clientes. Mas isto não é necessariamente um ponto positivo, pois pode ser que algum cliente não deseje atualizar o seu sistema.

Para fazer personalização neste modelo eu planejava usar `MEF` para fazer um load dinâmico de plugins para extender as funcionalidades do sistema para o *tenant*. E para a personalização das views pensei em utilizar uma estrutura assim: `{tenant}/Views/...`. Caso não existisse a view na pasta do cliente utilizaria uma view padrão do sistema mesmo.

**Mais algumas considerações**

O *tenant* acessará o sistema e poderá ter um site vinculado. Ex: acessando o site www.meusite.com.br ele poderá ver o "resultado" das informações que ele adicionou no sistema.
Nesse site o cliente do *tenant* poderá acessar uma área restrita. Os clientes do *tenant* dividem-se em 2 perfis: *A* e *B*.

Um exemplo para esclarecer melhor:

> Os *tenants* serão donos de concessionárias que poderão pegar carros usados para venda consignada. O *tenant* adiciona o carro no sistema e logo ele fica visível no site para o cliente com o perfil 'Cliente'. Este perfil pode ter uma 'lista de desejos' por exemplo. E o cliente com perfil 'Proprietário' também pode acessar o site em uma área restrita para poder ver como estão as questões relacionadas ao seu veículo.

Explicado a situação as dúvidas restantes são a seguinte:

- Utilizando o modelo isolado o SGBD ficaria com muitas bases de dados. Quais seriam as possíveis implicações disto?
- Utilizando o modelo compartilhado, as operações no banco de dados não teriam uma perda de performance devido ao filtros necessários para garantir o acesso à somente aos dados do *tenant*?
- Ainda no modelo compartilhado, o crescente número de registros na tabela seria mais um empecilho para a performance?
- Em relação à escalabilidade de uma aplicação com esta estrutura, o que seria possível fazer para evitar problemas de performance?
- Seria uma boa ideia utilizar `MEF` para carregar extensões para `controllers` com a finalidade de adicionar funcionalidades?
- Seria possível fazer que o site do *tenant* seja redirecionado para o conteúdo 'público' do sistema?
- Como poderia automatizar a criação desses *tenants* para reduzir a interação humana?
- Seria ainda possível disponibilizar caixas de e-mail personalizadas para estes *tenants*. Ex: contato@meusite.com.br.

Comment: Você poderia detalhar melhor as 3 últimas perguntas? Não ficou claro o que seria o conteúdo "público", o que você entende como automatizar a criação de tenants e sua dificuldade específica com as caixas de e-mail.

Comment: Essa resposta vai ficar enorme. Vou levar um tempo pra digitar tudo.

Comment: @Dherik o conteúdo público é como no exemplo da conceissionário. Tem a visão administrativa do sistema e uma visão como um site, onde seria como um mostruário dos veículos cadastrados, com opção de filtros pré-definidos. Em relação a automatização seria algo como: O tenant faz o pagamento on-line e a criação da base de dados e das demais informações necessárias para ele utilizar o sistema são geradas sem a necessidade de interação humana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Utilizando o modelo isolado o SGBD ficaria com muitas bases de dados. Quais seriam as possíveis implicações disto?**

Você teria uma dificuldade maior na manutenção do banco, pois os scripts SQL teriam que ser aplicados várias vezes ao invés de uma única vez e teria que monitorar vários bancos (nada que uma boa ferramenta não resolva). Mas, fora isto, este é o melhor cenário na minha opinião, pois: já garante que um tenant não verá dados de outro, diminui o risco de um problema de corrupção afetar todos tenant, possibilidade mover um banco específico para outro ambiente, aplicar soluções específicas para determinados perfis de consulta ao banco, etc.

**Utilizando o modelo compartilhado, as operações no banco de dados não teriam uma perda de performance devido ao filtros necessários para garantir o acesso à somente aos dados do tenant?**

Haverá, mas não seria tão significativa. Este problema em específico seria o menor dos seus problemas em uma aplicação assim, ao meu ver. Me preocuparia mais com a próxima pergunta na questão de performance.

**Ainda no modelo compartilhado, o crescente número de registros na tabela seria mais um empecilho para a performance?**

Se esta aplicação prevê muitos registros em algumas tabelas, você provavelmente terá problemas de performance, uma vez que terá uma única base os dados para todos os tenant. E este problema afetará na mesma magnitude mesmo os tenants que tem poucos registros.

**Em relação à escalabilidade de uma aplicação com esta estrutura, o que seria possível fazer para evitar problemas de performance?**

WebApi: uso de [http cache](http://blog.developers.ba/simple-way-implement-caching-asp-net-web-api/).

Entity Framework: uso de [cache de segundo nível](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh394143.aspx).

Banco de dados: assumindo que todas as FKs já tem índice, seria acompanhar de perto as consultas mais comuns no banco de dados e criar índices para os dados que elas acessam também. Estas consultas podem ser identificadas por [ferramentas de terceiros próprias para isto](http://www.solarwinds.com/pt/database-performance-analyzer-sql-server.aspx) ou acompanhando a performance do sistema por alguma outra ferramenta de monitoramento geral, como o [NewRelic](http://newrelic.com/), atuando pontualmente nas consultas que mais estão causando problemas de lentidão. De qualquer modo, recomendo que um DBA experiente possa acompanhar isto e ajudar.

**Seria uma boa ideia utilizar MEF para carregar extensões para controllers com a finalidade de adicionar funcionalidades?**

Vou ficar devendo esta resposta agora, vou ler antes sobre MEF :).

Mas depende do grau de customização que planeja ter entre os tenant. Algumas customizações creio que poderiam ser estendidas para todos os tenant. É importante avaliar isto para facilitar não só a sua vida, mas para deixar todos tenant mais felizes.

Agora, se as customizações são realmente particulares, você também pode se interessar de ler sobre [External Assembly](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/using-controllers-from-an-external-assembly-in-asp-net-web-api/).

De todo modo, seria importante detalhar qual grau de customização você espera por tenant, pois cada caso pode ser resolvido de maneira diferente: eles terão apenas regras de negócio distintas para a mesma funcionalidade? As telas são iguais para todos mas com validações diferentes? Existem muitas telas particulares para os tenants? Haverá funcionalidades inteiras presentes apenas em um dos tenants?

**Seria possível fazer que o site do tenant seja redirecionado para o conteúdo 'público' do sistema?**

Na aplicação, não vejo problemas particulares de um sistema multi-tenant para resolver isto. Você poderá controlar sem problemas os diferentes tipos de perfil dos usuário de cada tenant e qual parte do site ele vai acessar, pois a lógica estará no perfil (que é comum a todos tenant, pois o perfil "Proprietário" existirá em todos).

**Como poderia automatizar a criação desses tenants para reduzir a interação humana?**

Se fala de criar um novo tenant assim que surgir um novo, a melhor maneira será por scripts que preparam isto para você. Como a plataforma é Microsoft, seria com PowerShell. Por tudo o que me falou, deverá ser feito:

- Criação do banco de dados. O script em PowerShell conectaria-se ao banco de dados e criaria o banco ([sim, é possível](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048822/is-it-possible-to-create-a-database-in-sql-server-with-powershell)).
- Criação das tabelas e preenchimento das tabelas de domínio. Imaginando que usará algum mecanismo de migração de banco (como o FluentMigrator), bastaria executar ele para popular o banco recém criado.
- População das informações particulares do tenant. Configuração de SMTP, caminho para o logo do tenant, conta de superusuário do tenant, e-mail dele, etc. Seria todas as configurações que pertencem somente a cada tenant e que, na minha opinião, poderiam estar no banco de dados de cada tenant para este tipo de aplicação.
- (opcional) Criação de novos diretórios na aplicação. Imaginando que seguirá com a ideia de `{tenant}/Views`, o script criará este diretórios que são unicamente dos tenant. Mas acho que é isto será necessário apenas quando o tenant realmente precisar destes diretórios, que pelo que entendi seria nos momentos que o tenant teria uma tela própria ou algo do gênero.

**Seria ainda possível disponibilizar caixas de e-mail personalizadas para estes tenants. Ex: contato@meusite.com.br.**

Creio que a pergunta anterior responda esta. Você deixaria estas configurações no banco de dados do tenant.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta, assim como a do @CiganoMorrisonMendes esclareceram muitas das minhas dúvidas. Pelo que entendi, você optaria pelo modelo isolado, correto? Como você faria para controlar a questão de versionamento de cada tenant assim como as customizações realizadas para eles?

Comment: Sim, modo isolado. Se fala do versionamento de cada tenant no controle de versionamento (Git, Svn, etc), eu tentaria manter todos na mesma branch. Se criar uma branch para cada tenant, as chances da branch de cada tenant virarem uma "nova aplicação" e você perder o controle (mesmo fazendo rebase/merge) é alta. As customizações podem ser de diferentes níveis podendo ter diferentes soluções. Infelizmente, acho difícil existir uma resposta "matadora" que resolverá todos os casos de customização. Se quiser, dê mais detalhes na pergunta do grau de customização que espera ter na aplicação.

Answer (score 1):

## Utilizando o modelo isolado o SGBD ficaria com muitas bases de dados. Quais seriam as possíveis implicações disto?

Seria necessário uma publicação por cliente. Daria um pouco de trabalho, mas com um script é possível automatizar.

## Utilizando o modelo compartilhado, as operações no banco de dados não teriam uma perda de performance devido ao filtros necessários para garantir o acesso à somente aos dados do tenant?

Teriam, naturalmente. Você estaria lidando o tempo todo com um identificador de cliente. É uma coluna a mais e, portanto, mais um ônus para a performance. Com uma boa arquitetura, esse problema não é sentido.

## Ainda no modelo compartilhado, o crescente número de registros na tabela seria mais um empecilho para a performance?

Se sua arquitetura não estiver de acordo, sim.

## Em relação à escalabilidade de uma aplicação com esta estrutura, o que seria possível fazer para evitar problemas de performance?

Depende da tecnologia de banco de dados, mas como dito acima, se sua aplicação tem uma boa arquitetura os problemas são mitigados naturalmente.

Para bancos de dados relacionais, seria interessante estudar a performance das consultas. [Há um estudo intenso de planos de consulta neste artigo](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/247254/Improving-Entity-Framework-Query-Performance-Using). Outra alternativa seria usar o [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) juntamente com o Entity Framework para cache de consultas.

## Seria uma boa ideia utilizar MEF para carregar extensões para controllers com a finalidade de adicionar funcionalidades?

Se a aplicação não for gigantesca, não.

[MEF é recomendado para sistemas enormes e extensíveis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Caso seu sistema não tenha este requisito (o que, sinceramente, não acho que seja o caso), não há necessidade de usar.

## Seria possível fazer que o site do tenant seja redirecionado para o conteúdo 'público' do sistema?

Sim. Tudo depende do padrão de design que será usado para a aplicação tenente.

## Como poderia automatizar a criação desses tenants para reduzir a interação humana?

Seria ainda possível disponibilizar caixas de e-mail personalizadas para estes tenants. Ex: contato@meusite.com.br.

Fica mais a título de sugestão: evite chaves primárias numéricas e sequenciais. É sabido que o uso de `Guids` penaliza a aplicação em pelo menos 10% de *overhead*, mas o ganho em implementação compensa o ônus, como por exemplo a possibilidade de unir as bases sem se preocupar com as chaves.

Já a questão das caixas de entrada é um problema mais amplo: você teria que ter um mecanismo de sincronia de DNS, de endereços SMTP, IMAP, POP... Possível é, mas não seria algo simples.

Comment: Levando em consideração a sua experiência, por qual opção você optaria, pela compartilhada ou pela isolada?

Comment: Além disso, você teria alguma sugestão para a modelagem desta arquitetura ou uma referência para eu me basear?
Outra questão é: o uso de ORM's não adiciona um overhead para a realização das consultas?

Comment: Eu faria a isolada por motivos de coesão e simplicidade de base. Um bom começo [seria este artigo](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/848111/Multi-Tenancy-System-With-Separate-Databases-in-MV). O uso de ORM's adiciona overheads sempre, mas é um ônus quase imperceptível dada a facilidade de construir a aplicação.